# Vending Machine Program and printing array

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods

I'm creating a Vending Machine program for a class that is supposed to read a text file and take the items from said text file to populate an array of item Objects. When I go to print the array however, this is what the JVM shoots out.

> Item@3d4eac69

I've debugged the program to see if the file was being read correctly and the values were being input correctly and sure enough they were. I've tried just about everything I can think of and, as a beginner, I don't know what to do. I'll include my code below. The VendingMachine constructor was supplied to us by the instructor.

VendingMachine.java
    import java.io.*;

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class VendingMachine {

//data members
private Item[] stock;  //Array of Item objects in machine
private double money;  //Amount of revenue earned by machine
private Item[] vendor;

/*********************************************************************
 * This is the constructor of the VendingMachine class that take a
 * file name for the items to be loaded into the vending machine.
 *
 * It creates objects of the Item class from the information in the 
 * file to populate into the stock of the vending machine.  It does
 * this by looping the file to determine the number of items and then
 * reading the items and populating the array of stock. 
 * 
 * @param filename Name of the file containing the items to stock into
 * this instance of the vending machine. 
 * @throws FileNotFoundException If issues reading the file.
 *********************************************************************/
public VendingMachine(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException{
    //Open the file to read with the scanner
    File file = new File(filename);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

    //Determine the total number of items listed in the file
    int totalItem = 0;
    while (scan.hasNextLine()){
        scan.nextLine();
        totalItem++;
    } //End while another item in file
    //Create the array of stock with the appropriate number of items
    stock = new Item[totalItem];
    scan.close();

    //Open the file again with a new scanner to read the items
    scan = new Scanner(file);
    int itemQuantity = -1;
    double itemPrice = -1;
    String itemDesc = "";
    int count = 0;
    String line = "";

    //Read through the items in the file to get their information
    //Create the item objects and put them into the array of stock
    while(scan.hasNextLine()){
        line = scan.nextLine();
        String[] tokens = line.split(",");
        try {
            itemDesc = tokens[0];
            itemPrice = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
            itemQuantity = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);

            stock[count] = new Item(itemDesc, itemPrice, itemQuantity);
            count++;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.out.println("Bad item in file " + filename + 
                    " on row " + (count+1) + ".");
        }
    } //End while another item in file

    scan.close();

    //Initialize the money data variable.
    money = 0.0;

} //End VendingMachine constructor

//To run the successful transaction
public void vend() {

}

//To determine whether or not the transaction was successful 
public void outputMessage() {


}

//To print the items in held in stock
public void printMenu()  {
    vendor = stock;
    System.out.println(this.vendor[0]);

}




} //End VendingMachine class definition
```

VendingMachineDriver.java

```
import java.util.*;

import java.io.*;

public class VendingMachineDriver {



public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //String vendingSelect = input.next();
    String a = new String("a");
    String b = new String("b");
    String x = new String("x");



    System.out.println("Welcome to Jeremy's Super Vending Machines!");
    System.out.println("Please enter how much money you have:");
    System.out.println("Press A to select Drinks");
    //String vendingSelect = input.next();
    VendingMachine drinks = new VendingMachine("vending_machines/drinks");
    drinks.printMenu();



 }
}
```

Item.java (we were only told to have data members in this file and honestly I'm not sure why)

```
import java.util.*;

public class Item {
  private String itemDesc;
  private double itemPrice;
  private int itemQuantity;

  public Item (String itemDesc, double itemPrice, int itemQuantity){
      this.itemDesc = itemDesc;
      this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
      this.itemQuantity = itemQuantity;
}
```

}

Edit: forgot to add text files and there respective locations

drinks (location is vending_machines/drinks)

```
    Milk,2.00,1
    OJ,2.50,6
    Water,1.50,10
    Soda,2.25,6
    Coffee,1.25,4
    Monster,3.00,5
```

snacks (locations is vending_machines/snacks)

```
    Gummies,1.50,6
    Chips,1.00,6
    Raisins,1.25,5
    Pretzels,1.50,6
    Cookie,1.75,5
    Peanut,1.25,4
    Gum,0.75,2
```

Comment: you need to override `toString` in `item` if you want it to print "usefull" information for you if you print the object directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add / override the toString method of the Items Class

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "c1 [itemDesc=" + itemDesc + ", itemPrice=" + itemPrice + ", itemQuantity=" + itemQuantity + "]";
    }
```

Otherwise is java printing a hash code of the object and not Human Readable info...

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you very much. This was probably covered in lecture but I've missed some days. This solved my extremely frustrating problem that nearly brought me to tears haha

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `toString()` method to print the contents of the objects properly.

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to `print an Item`, the gibberish you see is actually the internal representation and the hash code of the object. This can be solved if `Item` has its own toString method. This can be achieved by adding the following to your `Item` class.

```
public String toString() {
    return "Description: " + this.itemDesc + 
           " | Price: " + this.itemPrice + 
           " | Quantity: " +  this.itemQuantity;
}
```

NOTE: adding the `@Override` tag to this method is good style. Works without it too, though.

If you want an understanding of why this happened, recall that all classes in Java extend the `Object` class. If a class doesn't have it's own `toString()` method defined, it falls back to using that of the `Object` class, which looks like this.. [notice the `@` in there - that's exactly what you have :) ]

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```